# Alert manager in Prometheus not starting

Tags: prometheus, prometheus-alertmanager

I configured Prometheus Alertmanager -
no error in installation but
`systemctl status alertmanager.service` gives

```
# systemctl status alertmanager.service
● alertmanager.service - Alertmanager for prometheus
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/alertmanager.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2021-11-12 07:15:08 UTC; 4min 50s ago
    Process: 1791 ExecStart=/opt/alertmanager/alertmanager --config.file=/opt/alertmanager/alertmanager.yml --storage.path=/opt/alertmanager/data (code=exited, status=1/FAILUR>
   Main PID: 1791 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Nov 12 07:15:08 localhost systemd[1]: alertmanager.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 5.
Nov 12 07:15:08 localhost systemd[1]: Stopped Alertmanager for prometheus.
Nov 12 07:15:08 localhost systemd[1]: alertmanager.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Nov 12 07:15:08 localhost systemd[1]: alertmanager.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Nov 12 07:15:08 localhost systemd[1]: Failed to start Alertmanager for prometheus.
```

My systemd service file for alertmanager.service is:

```
 [Unit]
Description=Alertmanager for prometheus

[Service]
Restart=always
User=prometheus
ExecStart=/opt/alertmanager/alertmanager --config.file=/opt/alertmanager/alertmanager.yml --storage.path=/opt/alertmanager/data            
ExecReload=/bin/kill -HUP $MAINPID
TimeoutStopSec=20s
SendSIGKILL=no

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

ExecStart=/opt/alertmanager/alertmanager --config.file=/opt/alertmanager/alertmanager.yml --storage.path=/opt/alertmanager/data (code=exited, status=1/FAILUR>

The logs say:

```
Nov 12 13:27:01 localhost alertmanager[1563]: level=warn ts=2021-11-12T13:27:01.483Z caller=cluster.go:177 component=cluster err="couldn't deduce an advertise address: no private IP found, explicit advertise addr not provided"
Nov 12 13:27:01 localhost alertmanager[1563]: level=error ts=2021-11-12T13:27:01.485Z caller=main.go:250 msg="unable to initialize gossip mesh" err="create memberlist: Failed to get final advertise address: No private IP address found, and explicit IP not provided"
Nov 12 13:27:01 localhost systemd[1]: alertmanager.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Nov 12 13:27:01 localhost systemd[1]: alertmanager.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

Any clues to resolve the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you want to run AlertManager in HA mode? It's enabled by default and requires an instance with RFC-6980 IP address.

You can specify this address with the flag `alertmanager --cluster.advertise-address=<ip>`

Otherwise disable HA with the specifying empty value for the flag: `alertmanager --cluster.listen-address=`